# How to formalise two relations/functions from one Set to another Set to another Set (HOL)?

Tags: functions, logic, relations, first-order-logic

Lets assume I have three sets A, B and C. I want to express that for all elements of set A there is at least one element of set B and for all those elements of set B, where there is a relation from A also an element from set C is existing (i tried to visualise it in the figure below).
If you look at the relations separately then those are easily formalised in first-order logic: $\forall a \in A \exists b\in B. R(a,b) $ and $\forall b \in B \exists c\in C. R(b,c) $

But if would like to say that for all possible relations from A to B there is also a relation to C I talk about a set of relations (or functions) and that seems to me like higher-order logic. Am I right with that?
Can anyone give me a hint how I can formalise that?
[visualisation of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qq2Pe.png)

Comment: Wouldn't this just be a surjection?

Comment: Quite convoluted proposal: $(\exists f \subseteq A \times B)(\forall a \in A)(\exists b \in B)((a,b) \in f) \land (\exists g \subseteq B \times C)(\forall b \in B)((\exists y \in A)((y,b) \in f) \to (\exists c \in C)((b,c) \in g)).$

Comment: Your informal description of the situation you want to describe is far from clear. What do you mean by "for all possible relations from $A$ to $B$, there is also a relation to $C$? Quantifying over relations is possible in first-order set theory as well as in higher-order logic, but you need to be clear about what you are trying to formalise.

Comment: Well I basically want to say that for all a in A there is a b in B. And for all those b, which have a relation to a, there is also a relation to C.